# How can I add parts of a column to a new pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas data frame of lenght 90 which isn't important 
Lets say I have :

```
df

A   date
1   2012-01-01
4   2012-02-01
5   2012-03-01
7   2012-04-01
8   2012-05-01
9   2012-06-01
2   2012-07-01
1   2012-08-01
3   2012-09-01
2   2012-10-01
5   2012-11-01
9   2012-12-01
0   2013-01-01
6   2013-02-01
```

and I have  created a new data frame

```
df_copy=df.copy() 
index = range(0,3)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=range((len(df_copy.columns))))
df1.columns = df_copy.columns                     

df1['date'] = pd.date_range('2019-11-01','2020-01-01' , freq='MS')-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

which should create a data frame like this

```
A   date
na   2019-10-01
na   2019-11-01
na   2019-12-01
```

So I use the following code to get the values of A in my new data frame

```
df1['A'] = df1['A'].iloc[9:12]
```

And I want the outcome to be this

```
A   date
2   2019-10-01
5   2019-11-01
9   2019-12-01
```

so I want that the last 3 values are assigned the value that has iloc position 9-12 in the new data frame, the indexes are different and so are the dates in both data frames. Is there a way to do this because

```
 df1['A'] = df1['A'].iloc[9:12]
```

doesn't seem to work

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You'll need to format your question a bit better and add some runnable code. Hard to decrypt what you are asking as the question stands right now.

Comment: I don't get an error it actually doesn't do anything wolfblitza the second data frame stays the same

Comment: Felipe Faria Shure give me a second and I will edit it

Comment: then try print(df1) - do you get the desired result?

Comment: wolfblitza I don't get the desired results using print(df1)

Comment: This is a bit strange. Why is it rows 9-12? How can there be no way to do this without hardcoding values? Also please include your data in a format that is easy for others to use. Even the output of `.to_dict()` is fine, as long as you can provide the precise DataFrame creation code we need (i.e the dtypes and column names).

Comment: Alexander Cécile I know its weird but , I need it to be those values, Yeah i could do it with out hardcoding and just going to the source and adding those three columns but I am trying to learn how to do this  by hardcoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge you can solve this by genearting several new data frames

```
df_copy=df.copy() 
index = range(0,1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=range((len(df_copy.columns))))
df1.columns = df_copy.columns                     

df1['date'] = pd.date_range('2019-11-01','2019-11-01' , freq='MS')-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
df1['A'] = df1['A'].iloc[9]
```

Then appending to your original data frame and repeating it is a bit overwhemling but it seems like the only solution i could came up with